# My links(a href) doesn't work

Tags: html

I have a problem that I don't understand, my links (a href = "...") doesn't work, someone sees a mistake?

```js
  $('.site-nav__item.has-dropdown').on('click tap', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var className = "is-active";
    $(this).toggleClass(className);
  });
```

```css
.site-header {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  .site-nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 75px;

    &__item {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 73px;
      float: left;
      &.has-dropdown {
        position: relative;

        &.is-active {
          .site-nav__dropdown { display: block; }
        }
      }
    }

    &__link {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      letter-spacing: 0.03em;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 23px;
      position: relative;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    &__dropdown {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      display: none;
      left: -37px;
      min-width: 225px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 75px;
      
      &__item {
        line-height: 60px;
        text-transform: inherit;
        .site-nav__link {
          font-size: 1.4rem;
          text-transform: inherit;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="site-nav__links">
      <li class="site-nav__item has-dropdown">
        <a class="site-nav__link"> Click here </a>
        <ul class="site-nav__dropdown">
          <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
            <a href="codepen.io" class="site-nav__link">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
            <a href="google.com" class="site-nav__link">Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
            <a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Item 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </nav>
  </header>
```

The links are in dropdown, after clicking on the menu. The first link redirects to codepen, the second to google ... but it stuck somewhere.

Thank you !

Comment: Without the `https://` (or `//`) prefix, the links will be interpreted as *relative* paths, e.g. `codepen.io` means `{current protocol}://{your domain}/{current path}/codepen.io`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in your JS code. That prevents link from being a link basically.

Btw. Next time put the JS code here

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the http:// or https://

```
<ul class="site-nav__links">
    <li class="site-nav__item has-dropdown">
      <a class="site-nav__link"> Click here </a>
      <ul class="site-nav__dropdown">
        <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
          <a href="http://codepen.io" class="site-nav__link">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
          <a href="https://google.com" class="site-nav__link">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
          <a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the anchor tag to this

```
<li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
            <a href="https://codepen.io" class="site-nav__link">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav__dropdown__item">
            <a href="https://google.com" target="" class="site-nav__link">Item 2</a>
          </li>
```

If you are checking in codepen , right click on the link and open in new tab or you can set target to blank. Otherwise codepen will block opening of new site inside itself